# Cuda: Operating on images (linearized 2d arrays) with a single column of constant values

Tags: image-processing, cuda

I am processing images, which are long, usually a few hundred thousand pixel in length. The height is usually in the 500-1000 pixel range. The process involves modifying the images on a column by column basis. So, for example, I have a column of constant values that needs to be subtracted from each column in the image.

Currently I split the image into smaller blocks, put them into linearized 2d arrays. Then I make a linearized 2d array from the column of constant values that is the same size as the smaller block. Then a (image array - constant array) operation is done until the full image is processed.

Should I copy the constant column to the device, and then just operate column by column? Or should I try to make as large of a "constant array" as possible, and then perform the subtraction. I am not looking for 100% optimization or even close to that, but an idea about what the right approach to take is.

How can I optimize this process? Any resources to learn more about this type of processing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant memory is up to 64KB, so assuming your pixels are 4 bytes or less, then you should be able to handle an image height up to about 16K pixels, and still put the entire "constant column" in constant memory.

After that, you don't need to process things "column by column".  Constant memory is optimized for access when every thread is requesting the same value from constant memory, which perfectly describes your case.

Therefore, your thread code can be trivially simple:

```
#define MAX_COL_SIZE 1024
__constant__ float const_column[MAX_COL_SIZE];

__global__ void img_col_kernel(float *in, float *out, int num_cols, int col_size){

  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < num_cols)
    for (int i = 0; i < col_size; i++)
      out[idx+i*num_cols] = in[idx+i*num_cols] - const_column[i];
}
```

(coded in browser, not tested)

Set up `const_column` in your host code using `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` prior to calling `img_col_kernel`.  Call the kernel with a 1D grid including a total number of threads equal to or greater than your image width (`num_cols`).  Pass the "linearized 2D" pointers to your input and output images to the kernel (`in` and `out`).  The above kernel should run pretty fast, and essentially be bound by memory bandwidth for images of width 1000 or more.  For small images, you may want to increase the number of threads by dividing your image vertically into say, 4 pieces, and operate with 4 times as many threads (and 4 regions of constant memory).